# How do I count the number of call levels up to a point?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a console.log tree of called functions.
For example, lets say I have an object with the function `start` and inside I call another function called `hello` twice and inside I call a function called `dancing` 1 or 3 times. And the dancing method console.logs a random number, random times. And lets say each method console.logs its own name or the random number, manually put.

Let the marker be `-` in this example.

Finally I would want my console to look like:

```
start
-hello
--dancing
---123
-hello
--dancing
---432
---5435
---53
--dancing
--dancing
---654
```

The project is too large to manually put this AND I may have dynamic chains of calls so I need a automated system for this.

Hey, if you can recommend a lib for this, it would be totally fine.

I have thought about just putting a variable with the parent's level in the calls but again, I would have to modify all functions...EVERYWHERE.

Cheers!

Comment: Push a function name in an array in each function?

Comment: Asyncronity and the need to keep track of the levels prevents me from doing this.

Comment: You can also do this dynamically with functionArray = arguments.callee.toString(); in every function.

Comment: Are you trying to track the flow of a request through your code, even through async methods? Does your code have a concept of "session" for each workflow? Each workflow would need to track it's progress independently, and then later correlate the various function calls.

Comment: And while you could fix the prototypes of functions automatically (and dynamic functions) to include tracing data, I'd still consider this to be reasonably complex. Any automated system would track everything, which may cause perf issues. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Yes WiredPrairie, but because of scopes, you wouldn't really need to track anything, assuming its somehow possible to measure how deep the call chain you are. Else I can put a variable in the calling of methods, and the called methods use the value of the parent(passed through a parameter or something ) + 1. I won't pursue this if it gets too complicated. Its just that I have a ton of logs and this would greatly improve the readability. Ignore the async issues, its fast enough to look synced.